# javax Mail gets the same message multpile times

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

my application opens an `IMAPFolder` and the first time gets the messages with `folder.getMessages`, then i store the UID that will be assigned to the next message in a member variable: `nextUID=folder.getUIDNext();`
When i open the folder again, i use `folder.getMessagesByUID(nextUID, folder.LASTUID);` but even though there has been no new mail since the first time, it still returns an 1-element array containg the mail that was already there the first time. How can in only get the new mails?

Answer (score 0):

From the JavaDoc : `LASTUID` 
          This is a special value that can be used as the end parameter in `getMessagesByUID(start, end)`, to denote the UID of the **last** message in the folder.
Therefore although your `start` parameter refers to a non-existent UID, the use of `LASTUID` causes the latest message to be retreived again, as it is in range.

Comment: ok, so it would be sufficient to just check and only call the mthod if `nextUID>=folder.LASTUID `

Comment: Instead of LASTUID, use `0xffffffff`, the largest possible UID value.